# ZipException: duplicate entry: io/codetail/animation/RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedGingerbread

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-4.4-kitkat

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: io/codetail/animation/RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedGingerbread.class
```

This are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'konifar:fab-transformation:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Because you have a duplicate dependency for this `io.codetail.animation` library

Comment: Have you followed how to add the dependency? https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal#how-to-add-dependency

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont even have it in my dependencies...,

Comment: Some library you are using depends on it, then

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added my dependencies...,

Comment: Thanks, and do you have any jars in the `libs/` folder?

Comment: I would recommend starting by removing the following. `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`, `'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'`, (definitely this next one) `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'`

Comment: @cricket_007I removed this   compile 'konifar:fab-transformation:1.0.0' and it worked...,